# JBOSS EAP 7 - Disable Trace Method

Tags: jboss7.x, trace, jboss-eap-7, disable

For security findings, we would like to disable certain HTTP methods like  DELETE, TRACE in JBoss EAP 7. Is there a way to do this by using JBoss configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `disallowed-methods` on the Undertow subsystem. `TRACE` is disabled by default. With CLI it would look something like:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=disallowed-methods, value=["TRACE", "DELETE"])
```

This can also be done in the Web Console as well.

Comment: Hi , can we set it through the standalone.xml?

Comment: That will set the value in the standalone.xml. It's really best to use a management client of some sort to make changes like that. That said you can. The path above for the command should lead you in the right direction.